# Understanding Fancybox image gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am playing around with Fancybox image galleries and having a bit of trouble understanding how the code works. Here's is my version of the code from Fancybox's demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Fancybox Image Gallery demo</title>

<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://photopedia.com.au/jquery/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://photopedia.com.au/jquery/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

  <style type='text/css'>
    #links {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#links li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

#links li label {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#links li.active label {
    background-color: white;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    nextEffect  : 'fade',
    prevEffect  : 'fade',
    padding     : 0,
    margin      : [15, 15, 40, 15],
    afterLoad   : addLinks,
    beforeClose : removeLinks
});

function addLinks() {
    var list = $("#links");

    if (!list.length) {    
        list = $('<ul id="links">');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
            $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() { $.fancybox.jumpto( $(this).data('index'));}).appendTo( list );
        }

        list.appendTo( 'body' );
    }

    list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq( this.index ).addClass('active');
}

function removeLinks() {
    $("#links").remove();    
}
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</body>


</html>
```

Works fine, but I don't understand how. It looks like the javascript builds a UL called #links out of the items on the page and uses the list to cycle through different images. What I don't understand is how it distinguishes what elements to use in the list. I would like to use it to make a gallery of items whose class is 'element' and contain an image and some other details but until I understand this first step I am a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read the [Setup](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions). All code related to #links has nothing to do with fancybox code and is not part of Fancybox. It is part of the demo only. You just need to set up your html like this (using your class of element :

```
<a class="element" rel="group" href="big_image_1.jpg"><img src="small_image_1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="element" rel="group" href="big_image_2.jpg"><img src="small_image_2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

and your fancy box code is like this:

```
$(".element").fancybox({
nextEffect  : 'fade',
prevEffect  : 'fade',
padding     : 0,
margin      : [15, 15, 40, 15]
});
```

All your possible options are [Here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). If you want to open more than just images, read the docs on how to open an inline, iframe or ajax link.